# Android Studio - pick a resource window not showing Images I stored in the drawable folder

Tags: android

When I stored some images inside the drawable folder under resources, I can not access them when I'm in the pick a resource window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing them from the project and simply drag and drop them on the resource window. Sometimes because of the naming conventions it could happen.

Comment: Awesome, please accept the answer if it solved your question for others.